# TYPO3 field helpers / hints / tips

Tags: forms, field, typo3

since I'm pretty new to TYPO3 I'd like to know is there a possibility of adding simple text hints / tips below any type of field, something like this, for Nickname input field:

[image: hints / tips for form fields]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Out of the box, not yet.
We are discussing a generic way to do so as we speak, but right now you'd need to create your own renderType for FormEngine.
Given the amount of PHP knowledge you have this is easy to intermediate.

Here are the steps:

### Step 1: add your own formEngine Type class in ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['formEngine']['nodeRegistry'][1463078603] = array(
    'nodeName' => 'ApparelCalculation',
    'priority' => 40,
    'class' => \T3G\Apparel\FormEngine\ApparelCalculation::class,
 );
```

The number 1463078603 should be unique, so a good idea is to use the current unix-timestamp for that.

### Step 2: Instruct your field to use that renderType

Add a TCA override file in `YOUR_EXTENSION/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php` (in this case we're overriding tt_content, thus the name. If you want to reconfigure another table in TYPO3, use the filename according to the tablename.

Add something along this:
`$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['header']['config']['renderType'] = 'ApparelCalculation';`

See how the `renderType` name is identical to what we registered in step 1.

### Step 3: Render what you like to render

I'll add the configuration of my special case class here, but I will cover the important things later in this post:

It might be helpful for your case to copy from `backend/Classes/Form/Element/InputTextElement.php` since that seems to be the element you want to put your tip to.

```
<?php
namespace T3G\Apparel\FormEngine;

use T3G\Apparel\Calculation\Calculation;
use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\Element\AbstractFormElement;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;


class ApparelCalculation extends AbstractFormElement
{

    /**
     * Renders the Apparel Calculation Table
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function render()
    {
        $resultArray = $this->initializeResultArray();
        $calculator = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Calculation::class);
        $resultTable = $calculator->calculateOrder($this->data['databaseRow']['uid']);
        $resultArray['html'] = $resultTable;
        return $resultArray;
    }
}
```

I won't focus on things outside the `render()`method, because that's just plain PHP.

It is important to call `$this->initializeResultArray();` first, so TYPO3 can work its magic to gather all the data.

From here on I'd suggest to use xdebug to get a grip of what you have available in that class.

The amount of information is **very** dense, but you will have everything there you need to build even the craziest stuff.

Now that you know how everything plays together you might think about extending `backend/Classes/Form/Element/InputTextElement.php` with plain PHP, grab the result of the parent `render()` call and simply add your tip to it.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you Mathias so much! I will try this out!